# XCode and Permissions

Tags: xcode, shell

I'm an admin on my macbook pro, however I'm having a situation in which for example in XCode, when trying to run a post build script, it complains that I don't have the necessary permissions. If I try to run XCode as a sudo then it changes the path of my current executing user making some bits of the script unusable.

Note: I'm not trying to execute any weird script, a simple mkdir and cp are failing.

My question would be two:
- Why I'm having this permissions issue, I'm an admin after all.
- How can I solve it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permissions of the path to the `mkdir` - if it's not writable by your current user, then the `mkdir` will fail.

This typically happens when you have messed up the permissions of the directory, or are trying to move a file into one of the system directories which requires administrative privileges. You do not have administrative permissions on these directories by default.

By default, you do not run with 'administrator privileges', you run as an ordinary user that can be elevated to administrator by the `sudo` or a GUI elevation prompt (the dialog that asks for an administrator username/password).

If you want to run the script with administrator privileges, then you can do:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "/path/to/script args" with administrator privileges'
```

this will trigger the elevation prompt.

Comment: In fact, after doing a bit of checks I realised there were some permissions issues on that folder, pretty much messed up. I didn't need to use the command you posted, I fix on the permissions did the trick. Thanks.